# Shell Script output indentation

Tags: linux, unix, shell, format

I want to call a shell-script / application inside another script. Every line of the contained script should be indented by 2 spaces. Is this possible?

The output should look something like this.

```
I'm the main-scripts' output.
  I'm a second script, called inside the main-script.
  Every line of my output is indented by 2 spaces.
  This is not implemented inside of me, but in the main-script
  as I should also be called outside of the main-script and then
  my output shouldn't be indented.
Thats all from the second script.
```

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `sed` or `awk` to do this. For example in your main script you could do:

```
# execute the command and pipe to sed
second-script | sed 's/\(.*\)/  \1/'
```

The above `sed` command simply prepends two spaces to each line of output from `second-script`.

Answer (score 6):

As always in Unix, there are options.

### `paste`

Use the `paste` utility with a blank LHS file, for example:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | paste /dev/null -
```

The `cat` command is a placeholder for your second script.

The `paste` command is designed to take two files and put them together, e.g.:

```
$ paste file1 file2
file 1 line 1    <TAB>  file 2 line 1
file 1 line two  <TAB>  file 2 line 2
file 1 line 3    <TAB>  file 2 line iii
```

The way I'm using it above is to use `/dev/null` as `file1`, and `STDIN` as `file2`, specified by `-`. When used as input, `/dev/null` returns NULL characters. This means every line of `file2`, the output of your second script, is preceded by NULL followed by a TAB character.

You can go further: `paste` has a `--delimiter` option, but specifying two spaces doesn't give the expected effect: *delimiter 1* is used between the first and second columns, *delimiter 2* is used between the second and third, and so on.

### `paste|expand`

To get a two-space indent, you would use the plain `paste` piped again through `expand -2`: this turns all tabs into two spaces:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | paste /dev/null - | expand -2
```

This will behave exactly as you specified.

### `sed` or `awk`

Yet another approach is to use `sed` or `awk`:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | sed 's/^/  /'
```

This searches for the beginning of line ("`^`"), and substitutes, or really inserts a pair of spaces.

```
cat ~/.bashrc | awk '{printf "  %s\n",$0}'
```

This takes each full line ("`$0`") and formats it with `printf`, using the format specifier of two spaces, followed by the string to be printed, followed by a newline.

---

Bear in mind all of the above commands can eliminate the `cat` piece of the pipeline, i.e. `paste /dev/null ~/.bashrc`, or `paste /dev/null ~/.bashrc|expand -2`, equally `sed 's/^/  /' ~/.bashrc` or `awk '{printf "  %s\n",$0}' ~/.bashrc`. It's often taken as a beginner error to use `cat` first in a pipeline.

Comment: +1 for a cleaner use of sed

Comment: @JimL. I just realized I'm committing the heinous sin of `cat ... | <command>` where `paste`, `sed`, and `awk` all take a filename as an argument. _hangs head in shame_ In my defence, the answer to "what was I thinking?" appears to be _clarity_, so that the filename is always in the same place whichever alternative is used.